# Visual C++ - An hunhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll (Windows 8)

Tags: visual-c++

I'm italian and I was forced to sign up for tell you what is my problem using Visual C++ (Windows Form Application).

```
#pragma once

namespace test {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog^  folderBrowserDialog1;

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->folderBrowserDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FolderBrowserDialog());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(316, 9);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(316, 53);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button2->Text = L"button2";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(28, 9);
            this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(278, 23);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(28, 53);
            this->textBox2->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(278, 23);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(133, 102);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button3->Text = L"button3";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
            // 
            // folderBrowserDialog1
            // 
            this->folderBrowserDialog1->HelpRequest += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(453, 170);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 OpenFileDialog^ chooseDirectory = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
                 chooseDirectory->ShowDialog();
                 textBox1->Text = chooseDirectory->FileName;
             }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 FolderBrowserDialog^ fbd = gcnew FolderBrowserDialog;
                 fbd->ShowDialog();
                 textBox2->Text = fbd->SelectedPath;
             }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             File::Move(textBox1->Text, textBox2->Text);
             MessageBox::Show("Success","File's directory has been changed!", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
         }
private: System::Void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
};
}
```

I don't know the reason, but it doesn't works! I only want to move the file choosen (using OpenFileDialog) to another directory (using FolderBrowserDialog).

I don't know what i should do. PLEASE HELP ME! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it made you sign up because you're italian - we all have to.

Comment: At what point does it fail? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: File::Move() requires a **file** name for the second argument.  Right now you are trying to overwrite the directory with the file, that's a kaboom.  Use Path::Combine() to generate a valid file name.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you tell me how should i use Path::Combine()?

Comment: String^ dest = Path::Combine(textBox2->Text, Path::GetFileName(textBox1->Text));

Comment: @HansPassant it's incredible :O it works! Can you explain me better (in an elementary way) what does that code do? And where did you learn how to made windows form applications on Visual C++? Thanks, thanks!!!